# Use a Data Grid Table to assign values to an EAV attribute in admin

Tags: magento2, adminform, eav, product-grid

I have a custom attribute for Catalog Categories that represents the IDs of products associated with the category in question (this is a separate requirement from the usual association of products and categories). The values are stored as comma separated values in the db.

How would I go about using a data grid to select the products I want to add to this attribute? Ideally, I want it to be more or less the same experience as adding products to a category, but I need to to update my custom attribute.

I added the below to app/code/company/module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category.form.xml - but as you'd expect this just updates the native product/category association.

```
    <fieldset name="associated_products">
    <settings>
        <collapsible>true</collapsible>
        <label translate="true">Associated Products</label>
    </settings>
    <container name="assign_products_container">
        <htmlContent name="html_content">
            <block name="gallery" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\AssignProducts"/>
        </htmlContent>
    </container>
</fieldset>
```

This is the kind of thing I'm after:

[image]